# get source folder when executing globally installed npm cli package

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line-interface

I am creating my own CLI using NodeJS. One task of the CLI is to copy folders recursively from a source folder within the project.

So, I install my CLI globally using `npm install -g` from within my CLI project folder.
Now I can run it in another test folder.
However, when I run it, the recursive copy fails because it is trying to find the files from the source folder in the test folder I created. Not from `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/[myCli]`.

I have tried many solutions using `path` and `require.resolve` and `__filename` but they all give me a folder starting from the test folder in which I am executing my CLI.

Other then hardcoding the source path to `/usr/local/lib....`, there most be a way to get the folder of the globally executed script?

Comment: What do you have specified in the [``bin``](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin) section of your CLI tools _package.json_ file?

Comment: I have referenced the global name of the package there that points to the ‘./index.js’.

Comment: I am going to look at ‘ https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-installed-path’. That might work. Or I I have to exec an NPM command that gives me the modules location and construct the part from there on.

Answer (score 0):

If you search for the current working directory its process.cwd() https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_cwd

__filename give you only path of file where it installed in node_modules

To find your project files you can use rc file in your home directory containing the path of your project
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_commands

in hope this helps

Comment: Perhaps read the question again. OP says: **1)** They want _"the source path to `/usr/local/lib...`"_ - not  current working directory  **2)** OP also says  _"I have tried ... `__filename` but they all give me a folder starting from the test folder in which I am executing my CLI."_ Also your last solution, i.e. rc file, seems to entail hardcoding the path.

Comment: Exactly. I am not looking for the running fold of where I am executing the CLI, but the install folder of the cli module